# RGB to hexadecimal

Tags: code-golf, hexadecimal, color

> Based off a Scratch project

The pen extension in Scratch has a `set pen color to ()` block. The `()` is normally a color dropdown, but you can also use the `join()()` block. In the `join()()` block, normally a hex value is in the first input, but the second is just an empty string.

However, many new Scratchers that want to take advantage of this find it hard (after all we count in decimal). Your task today, is: given three positive integers `r`,`g`,`b`, calculate the hex value and return it as `#rrggbb`.

### Input:

`r`, `g`, `b`.

1. \$0\le r\le255\$
2. \$0\le g\le255\$
3. \$0\le b\le255\$
4. Input will always follow these rules
5. Input won't have leading zeros except for `0` itself

### Output

A string in the format `#rrggbb`. Hexadecimal letters can be all uppercase or all lowercase.

### Method

1. Convert `r`,`g`,`b` to hexadecimal
2. Concatenate `r`,`g`,`b`
3. Prepend a `#`
4. Return it

### Testcases:

```
r, g, b     -> Output

0, 127, 255   -> #007fff
1, 1, 1       -> #010101
245, 43, 2    -> #f52b02
72, 1, 134    -> #480186
0, 0, 0       -> #000000
255, 255, 255 -> #ffffff
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer wins!

**NOTE**: There's [an earlier question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/color-rgb-int-to-hex) that qualifies this as a duplicate, but it's closed (because the scoring criterion was ambiguous)

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't been asked already :p

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/43155/107299)

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that the inputed numebrs don't have leading zeros (barring `0` itself)?

Comment: You are allowed to assume that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `j`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Ḥ2ṛ'#
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faGm0UpZS7IKlpSVpuhYrH-5YYvRw52x15SXFScnFUNEFa6MNdBQMjcx1FIxMTWMhggA)

##### Explanation

```
Ḥ2ṛ'#  # Implicit input
Ḥ      # Convert each to hexadecimal
 2ṛ    # Pad each with 0s to length 2
   '#  # Push a "#" to the stack
       # Implicit output of joined stack
```

Answer (score 16):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 22 bytes

```python
("#"+"%02x"*3).__mod__
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrbCsIwEAXf9yuWiJDUIM2NitA/EYJgSwM1DWW9fX1cKwyHwzDlQ9OS3amsdewvVYqdOIh9a9@iceoY4325xVhfU5oHNGdA6ofndZYplwdJpQDLmjLJUZJStdVobKfRhgCGPwPWB43esYTO/p3zwOUP4HLLt/kC)

Takes inputs as a tuple. The idea is to avoid a `lambda` or `def` by [having the answer be an object method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95156/20260).

Same length:

```python
f"#{'%02x'*3}".__mod__
```

Comment: I never realised `%`-formatting is just a modulo overload

Comment: What does module overload mean?

Comment: @DialFrost Operator overloading happens when an operator acts differently depending on its arguments. The `%` operator (which refers to `<object>.__mod__`) is mostly used to perform the modulo operation, but in the case of strings it is used for formatting.

Answer (score 7):

## [`[5,171,30]` - 05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₁+h€¦J'#ì
```

Input as list `[r,g,b]`. Outputs in uppercase.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVOjdsajpjWHlnmpKx9e8/9/tKmOobmhjrFBLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/R02N2hmPmtYcWualrnx4zX@d/9HRhjpAGKsTbWRiqmNirGMEZJobgcSMTYBMAx1DI3MdI1NTMBsIQSpNTXWgGMgz1TE0N9QxNoiNBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
₁+         # Add 256 to each value in the (implicit) input-triplet
  h        # Convert each from integer to a hexadecimal string
   €¦      # Remove the leading "1" from each string
     J     # Join them together
      '#ì '# Prepend a leading "#"
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: [Alternative 9 byter](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/49xWo0cdvbXqykcXev3/H22gY2hkrmNkahoLAA "05AB1E – Try It Online"). Don't know if this can be golfed down more

Comment: @emirps I'm afraid it's incorrect for inputs in the range `[1,15]`. The `ε2∍}` will extend single hexadecimal characters (e.g. `5` to `55` instead of the intended `05`). So input `[5,171,30]` will result in `#55AB1E` instead of `#05AB1E` with your program. (PS: It could be golfed to 8 bytes by changing `ε2∍}` to `2δ∍` btw. :) In this case `δ` (double-vectorized builtin) works as a map on the given list with builtin `∍` and argument `2`.)

Answer (score 7):

## [C (GCC)](https://gcc.gnu.org), 39 bytes

```
m(r,g,b){printf("#%06x",r<<16|g<<8|b);}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjfVczWKdNJ1kjSrC4oy80rSNJSUVQ3MKpR0imxsDM1q0m1sLGqSNK1rocrTcxMz8zQ0Faq5OHM1jExNdaBY0xqmPSZPSdOaSwEIcjUMdBRACLukoZGFjoKhpZGOgoU5ugqodTBXAgA)

I could to this all day in every language

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 20 bytes

```
\(...)rgb(...,m=255)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhZbYjT09PQ0i9KTQLROrq2RqakmROrm2jQNAx0FQyNzHQWQqLKCgoKunYKygYF5WloaV5qGIVASiMASCjBJQxAEShqZmOoomBgDtULkQZJppkZJBkZASXMjiFZjE4SkiYWBoYUZF9hOEEI1FgxAxpqagl0DcxLYWDCAOHrBAggNAA)

Somehow, when I first posted this answer, I managed to overlook the linked related challenge, where it was clearly pointed out that R has a built-in for this specific task...

My original non-built-in solution:

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 38 bytes

```
cat("#",sprintf("%02x",scan()),sep="")
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN9WSE0s0lJSVdIoLijLzStI0lFQNjCqA3OTEPA1NTZ3i1AJbJSVNiOqVBgqGRuYKRqamED7MFAA)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 49 bytes

Not the right tool for the job.

Expects `[r,g,b]`.

```javascript
a=>'#'+a.map(x=>(x>>4&&'')+x.toString(16)).join``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZczRCoMgGIbh812FEKTSZmrWOsmb2OEY5LaKomlUjO6@ZcMO6v/hO3p4G/VVw6uvu/GizbuYy2xWmYQeDBT5qA5NmUSTlML3IcTBREZzG/taV4glGJPG1DrP55fRg2kL0poKlegOAD0DNw@MQRgCj653OlBm1X82yuzvKRfxokRkKXe0jPmT8j29cotslUXCUZFSliaHarxU3WzV9eYf)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes

Expects `r,g,b`.

```javascript
(r,g,b)=>'#'+(r+256<<16|g<<8|b).toString(16).slice(1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcxBDoMgEIXhfU9B0oUQrTII1AX2Ej2BWiU2Rho0XXl3KlY2zCRv9eV/N99m6ez4WW@zefVuqB22mc5aUj@Sa5JimzIhlQK5aaWqrSX5ap6rHWeNQZJ8mcaux0BcZ@bFTH0@GY0HjBDNUBhCUFGgKz3uEkPw5j8Bgv8IMi52w0sP2QkHwVrKInhnnvgilPyEvKJQybgo9mKYUDzO/QA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 7 bytes

```
H2↳›\#p
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBcyIsIiIsIkgy4oaz4oC6XFwjcCIsIiIsIlswLCAxMjcsIDI1NV1cblsxLCAxLCAxXVxuWzI0NSwgNDMsIDJdIl0=)

The benefits of string padding. And flags. Helps not be beaten by half a byte :p

### Explained

```
H2↳›\#p
H         # Convert each item in the input to hexadecimal
 2↳›      # append 0s until each string is of length 2
    \#p   # and prepend a "#" 
          # the s flag joins the top of the stack into a single string
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 19 bytes

```ruby
->*v{?#+"%02x"*3%v}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf106rrNpeWVtJ1cCoQknLWLWs9n@BQlq0oaGOkZGOsXEsF4hnoGNoZK5jZGoa@x8A)

Comment: Some other answers take input as an array, this would allow getting rid of the asterisk.

Answer (score 5):

## [Excel](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/excel), <sup><s>31</s></sup> 29 bytes

-7 bytes thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)

-2 bytes thanks to [Taylor Alex Raine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61846/taylor-alex-raine)

```
="#"&CONCAT(DEC2HEX(0&A1#,2))
```

Where `A1` contains the following: `={0,127,255}`.

[image]

Comment: "Hexadecimal letters can be all uppercase or all lowercase" = should save 7 bytes...

Comment: `="#"&z(A1)&z(B1)&z(C1)` and z is a named lambda function `=LAMBDA(a,DEC2HEX(a,2))`  ....I don't think this really counts as golfing, but it is 20+23+1= 44 characters .  (The +1 is for the letter z in the function name)

Comment: You can drop 2 bytes if you expect array input (`A1# `)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
”#2Øhṗị@‘
```

A full program that accepts a list of integers from \$[0,255]\$ and prints the resulting hexadecimal string.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//4oCdIzLDmGjhuZfhu4tA4oCY////WzI0NSwgNDMsIDJd)**

...a fair bit shorter than the naive approach of a monadic Link like `+⁹b⁴Ḋ€‘ịØh”#;` which comes in at 13 bytes - [TIO](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9qZWxsef//K@KBuWLigbThuIrigqzigJjhu4vDmGjigJ0jO////1syNDUsIDQzLCAyXQ).

#### How?

```
”#2Øhṗị@‘ - Main Link: list of integers, Colours
”#        - '#' character
            ... the chaining of `nilad nilad nilad` (”#2Øh)
                forces this to be printed to STDOUT with no trailing character(s)
  2       - two
   Øh     - hexadecimal characters -> "0123456789abcdef"
     ṗ    - Cartesian power -> ["00","01",...,"ff"]
        ‘ - increment (Colours) (vectorises)
       @  - with swapped arguments:
      ị   -   index into
          - implicit, smashing print
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 7.5 bytes (15 nibbles)

```
"#"+.$&"0"2hex
```

```
"#"+.$&"0"2hex
    .           # map over
     $          # each number in the input
           hex  # converting it to hexadecimal
      $         # and justifying it
          2     # to two characters wide
       "0"      # using "0" as filler,
   +            # then, flatten this list
"#"             # and prepend a "#" character.
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [CP-1610](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Instrument_CP1600) machine code, 34 DECLEs<sup>1</sup> = 42.5 bytes<sup>2</sup>

*<sub>1. A CP-1610 opcode is encoded with a 10-bit value (0x000 to 0x3FF), known as a 'DECLE'.</sub>*
*<sub>2. This routine is 34 DECLEs long, i.e. 340 bits. As per the exception described in [this meta answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10810/58563), the score is **42.5 bytes**.</sub>*

A routine expecting a pointer to three bytes in **R3** and writing the result at **R4** (in white, assuming ColorStack mode).

#### Test code

```
    |           |        ROMW    10            ; 10-bit ROM
    |           |        ORG     $4800         ; map the program at $4800
    |           |
4800|001        |        SDBD                  ; set up an ISR for minimal
4801|2B8 030 048|        MVII    #isr,   R0    ; STIC initialization
4804|240 100    |        MVO     R0,     $100
4806|040        |        SWAP    R0
4807|240 101    |        MVO     R0,     $101
    |           |
4809|002        |        EIS                   ; enable interrupts
    |           |
480A|001        |        SDBD                  ; R4 = BACKTAB pointer
480B|2BC 000 002|        MVII    #$200,  R4
480E|001        |        SDBD                  ; R3 = pointer to test cases
480F|2BB 01E 048|        MVII    #test,  R3
    |           |
4812|004 148 040|loop    CALL    rgb           ; invoke our routine
    |           |
4815|2FC 00D    |        ADDI    #13,    R4    ; advance to the beginning
    |           |                              ; of the next line
4817|001        |        SDBD
4818|37B 030 048|        CMPI    #done,  R3    ; done?
481B|225 00A    |        BLT     loop
    |           |
481D|017        |        DECR    R7            ; loop forever
    |           |
481E|000 07F 0FF|test    DECLE   0, 127, 255   ; #007fff
4821|001 001 001|        DECLE   1, 1, 1       ; #010101
4824|0F5 02B 002|        DECLE   245, 43, 2    ; #f52b02
4827|048 001 086|        DECLE   72, 1, 134    ; #480186
482A|000 000 000|        DECLE   0, 0, 0       ; #000000
482D|0FF 0FF 0FF|        DECLE   255, 255, 255 ; #ffffff
    |           |done
    |           |        ;; ------------------------------------------- ;;
    |           |        ;;  ISR                                        ;;
    |           |        ;; ------------------------------------------- ;;
    |           |isr     PROC
4830|240 020    |        MVO     R0,     $0020 ; enable display
4832|280 021    |        MVI     $0021,  R0    ; colorstack mode
    |           |
4834|1C0        |        CLRR    R0
4835|240 030    |        MVO     R0,     $0030 ; no horizontal delay
4837|240 031    |        MVO     R0,     $0031 ; no vertical delay
4839|240 032    |        MVO     R0,     $0032 ; no border extension
483B|240 028    |        MVO     R0,     $0028 ; black background
483D|240 02C    |        MVO     R0,     $002C ; black border
    |           |
483F|0AF        |        JR      R5            ; return from ISR
    |           |        ENDP
```

#### Routine ($4840-$4861)

```
    |           |        ;; ------------------------------------------- ;;
    |           |        ;;  our routine                                ;;
    |           |        ;; ------------------------------------------- ;;
    |           |rgb     PROC
4840|275        |        PSHR    R5            ; push the return address
    |           |
4841|2B8 01F    |        MVII    #$1F,   R0    ; draw the '#'
4843|260        |        MVO@    R0,     R4
    |           |
4844|2BA 003    |        MVII    #3,     R2    ; repeat 3 times
    |           |
4846|298        |@@loop  MVI@    R3,     R0    ; R0 = byte to display
4847|00B        |        INCR    R3            ; advance R3
4848|004 148 054|        CALL    @@hexa        ; draw the upper nibble
484B|04C        |        SLL     R0,     2     ; shift the lower nibble
484C|04C        |        SLL     R0,     2
484D|004 148 054|        CALL    @@hexa        ; draw it
4850|012        |        DECR    R2            ; loop?
4851|22C 00C    |        BNEQ    @@loop
    |           |
4853|2B7        |        PULR    R7            ; return
    |           |
4854|081        |@@hexa  MOVR    R0,     R1    ; copy R0 into R1
4855|3B9 0F0    |        ANDI    #$F0,   R1    ; isolate the upper nibble
4857|2F9 10F    |        ADDI    #$10F,  R1    ; add the offset for '0'
    |           |                              ; and set the lower nibble
    |           |                              ; so that we write in white
4859|379 19F    |        CMPI    #$19F,  R1    ; if greater than '9' ...
485B|206 002    |        BLE     @@print
    |           |
485D|2F9 270    |        ADDI    #$270,  R1    ; ... advance to 'a'
    |           |
485F|061        |@@print SLR     R1            ; right-shift to get the
    |           |                              ; final value
4860|261        |        MVO@    R1,     R4    ; write it
4861|0AF        |        JR      R5            ; return
    |           |        ENDP
```

#### Output

[image: output]

*<sup>screenshot from [jzIntv](http://spatula-city.org/%7Eim14u2c/intv/)</sup>*

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 20 bytes

```python
lambda x:"#"+x.hex()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrbCgIhFEXfz1ccphclibwxMDB/0otDDgpmIlb69WYTLDabxUqtuGeUfV9vPZjHdjdYl@k0nevF2Upo/zgfLPIFsKz2bQLxMb0KoRQwZR8L2cnWijU5m0YKpbRfGXIxMxRaAx9/AEJphkoOCbP4O6lglD9glEd@zBc)

Takes input as a `bytearray`.

Test bed borrowed from @xnor.

Answer (score 4):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>86 84 76 75 69 65 61</s> 57 bytes

```c
b;main(c){for(;~scanf("%d",&c);printf("#%02X"+!!b++,c));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/JOjcxM08jWbM6Lb9Iw7quODkxL01DSTVFSUctWdO6oCgzrwTIV1Y1MIpQ0lZUTNLW1knW1LSu/f/fQMHQyFzByNT0X3JaTmJ68X/dcgA)

- Kudos to @mousetail for shaving 2 bytes (from 86 to 84)
- Kudos to @corvus_192 for shaving 4 bytes (from 65 to 61)
- Kudos to @jdt for shaving 4 bytes (from 61 to 57)

#### Ungolfed with comments, courtesy of @jdt:

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 326 bytes

```c
// all global and static variables are initiated to 0. 
int b = 0; 

main(int c)
{
    // scanf will retun -1 when done. ~-1 = 0
    while (~scanf("%d",&c)) 
    {
	// Here we do some pointer arithmetic.
        char* format = "#%02X";
        printf(format + (b != 0) , c);

        // now we increment b
        b++;
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PU9LboMwEF3Xp3ilSgQlHxIp6iLqvkfodjADWDJ2ZNx6ESVHLx1oldnNvO/obaf1NO33IGvRWV@TBbkGY6RoNL4pGKotj6DAMM5EQ5EbRI9qB2VcRI13VGcoNZBx@XzRhboqyIjtqMm1SEbcA8cvh@0BqWeHxjve4S6ryBd26o1l5PdFkmerJtusdVFgAa/qSdw@WFokFjFGPzAuXvI4SDkT@4Gl8W5hz6N7Cq9ofRgoSkb2sqqOn9n5gV@CaNv8n1Air/EsVQps5IGzevAk1vk0pxqnAw88//xA67L8s7yp2zRVOBzfcDydfnRrqRunbfoF)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thanks! This was fun, and someone else already posted a better answer for C, hah!

Comment: Oh wait, so only a function definition counts for the size, not the whole program? Judging by this other submission: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254095/115435

Comment: The scoring rules get a bit complicated, but yeah, usually [you can just submit a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet). People will typically take the I/O and full program vs. function differences into account when comparing scores though, so if you prefer using `main(){...}` and `scanf` and stuff, nobody will think you're a worse golfer for it :p

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYFNckpKZr5dh9z83MTNPQ7M6M69EITHaONa6ODkxL01DSTVFRwGClXQSdRK1DYHYSNO6oAioECitrGpgFAHDQBXRBrFAwhBEGMVqWtf@/29oZKGjYGRqqqNgCgA) by removing the spaces in `scanf()`

Comment: Nice catch, thanks! Got it down to 75 by replacing it with a loop :D

Comment: -4 bytes: You can remove the `int` from `int c`.

Comment: TIL, awesome! "warning: type of ‘c’ defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]"

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using bitwise negation. Replace `scanf("%d,",&c)>0` with  `~scanf("%d,",&c)`.

Comment: [58 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/JOjcxM08jWbM6Lb9Iw7quODkxL01DSTVFR0lHLVnTuqAoM68EKKCsamAUoaStqJikra2TrKlpXfv/v4GOgqGRuY6Ckanpv@S0nMT04v@65QA)

Comment: [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/JOjcxM08jWbM6Lb9Iw7quODkxL01DSTVFSUctWdO6oCgzrwTIV1Y1MIpQ0lZUTNLW1knW1LSu/f/fQMHQyFzByNT0X3JaTmJ68X/dcgA) by removing the `,` from the `scanf`

Comment: added, I understand `~` but what is that sorcery with `b;`? and I could swear I had previously tried scanf with "%d" and it didn't work

Comment: @jdt oh you removed `,` from the input too, aren't we breaking input specification then?

Comment: The input rules are usually pretty relaxed. Here is an ungolfed version [TIO](https://tio.run/##PU9LboMwEF3Xp3ilSgQlHxIp6iLqvkfodjADWDJ2ZNx6ESVHLx1oldnNvO/obaf1NO33IGvRWV@TBbkGY6RoNL4pGKotj6DAMM5EQ5EbRI9qB2VcRI13VGcoNZBx@XzRhboqyIjtqMm1SEbcA8cvh@0BqWeHxjve4S6ryBd26o1l5PdFkmerJtusdVFgAa/qSdw@WFokFjFGPzAuXvI4SDkT@4Gl8W5hz6N7Cq9ofRgoSkb2sqqOn9n5gV@CaNv8n1Air/EsVQps5IGzevAk1vk0pxqnAw88//xA67L8s7yp2zRVOBzfcDydfnRrqRunbfoF)

Comment: ahh you're moving the string start pointer for 1 char so # doesn't get printed... neat!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <del>38</del> 23 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to @py3_and_c_programmer

```python
lambda*x:"#"+"%02x"*3%x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwdI0BVuFmKWlJWm6FjtyEnOTUhIVtCqslJSVtJVUDYwqlLSMVSsg0jctC4oy80o00jSMTE11oFhTkwsmamhkARY1QxIz0AFCTU2IAQsWQGgA)

Comment: That was blistering fast, but I suppose my challenge is too easy anyway...

Comment: 23 bytes: `lambda*x:"#"+"%02x"*3%x`

Comment: I left that for you as a test

Comment: What do you mean that was a test?

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl043`, 19 bytes

```perl
$\.=unpack H2,chr}{
```

[Try it online!](https://dom111.github.io/code-sandbox/#eyJsYW5nIjoid2VicGVybC01LjI4LjEiLCJjb2RlIjoiJFxcLj11bnBhY2sgSDIsY2hyfXsiLCJhcmdzIjoiLXBsMDQzIiwiaW5wdXQiOiIyNDVcbjQzXG4yIn0=)

### Explanation

Uses the commandline flag `-l043` to prepopulate `$\` with `'#'` and for each input line, appends the result of `unpack`ing the number to `H2` (`0`-padded hex representation).

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

```java
(r,g,b)->"".format("#%06x",r<<16|g<<8|b)
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Arnauld* by porting [@mousetail's C answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254095/52210).

Output in lowercase. Could be in uppercase by replacing the `x` with `X`.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##ZVDLbsIwELzzFautKtmyE5GQQFXS/kG59Fj1YAfjhiZO5BjUqvDtqRN8AKGVR9rZ13j24iii/fZ7KGvR9/AmKvM3A6iMU3YnSgWbMQV4d7YyGkriK2D5iHpCSde@4Tzz0DvhqhI2YOBlIJZrLmn0ihjvWtsIR/Dhcb78QW6LIlmedFE8nSQd1uNod5C1Hw0bjm21hcZLIZezH5@CXmQ41TuScB/T2UCkWc6zBU@vuVU6di2ya27Ok3TF0zy/JX3cbMtzHt7d3yZlU9e9D8Go396pJm4PLu68dlcbYhlyZHpCyfAZGQLGVnXKm5LMI4LIrK9LGtfKaPdFKGUmLoOFQcR5@Ac)

**Explanation:**

```java
(r,g,b)->             // Method with three integer parameters and String return-type
  "".format("#%06x",  //  Return a String with a format as:
             #        //   A leading hash "#"
              %  x    //   And an integer converted to a hexadecimal value
                6     //   of size 6
               0      //   with potential leading 0s if it's smaller than 6
                      //  Where the integer is:
    r<<16             //   Input `r` bitwise right-shifted by 16
    |                 //   Bitwise-ORed with
    g<<18             //   Input `g` bitwise right-shifted by 8
    |                 //   Bitwise-ORed with
    b)                //   Input `b` as is
```

Comment: Using [mousetail's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254095/58563) would be 1 byte shorter.

Comment: @Arnauld Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 49 bytes

```
.+
$*
%`^(.{16})*(.)*
$#1¶$#2
T`d`l`..
.\B|¶

^
#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg819Pm0tFi0s1IU5Dr9rQrFZTS0NPU4tLRdnw0DYVZSOukISUhJwEPT0uvRinmkPbuLjiuJT//zfQMTQy1zEyNeUy1AFCLiMTUx0TYx0jLnMjEN/YhMtABwi5gCp0oBgA) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on commas for convenience. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
%`^(.{16})*(.)*
$#1¶$#2
```

Divmod by `16`, resulting in a list of six integers from `0-15`.

```
T`d`l`..
```

Adjust `10-15` by transliterating `0-5` to `a-f`.

```
.\B|¶
```

Remove the leading digit from integers that used to be above `9` and join all of the digits together.

```
^
#
```

Prefix a `#`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 36 bytes

```julia
~x="#"*(string.(x,base=16,pad=2)...)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdDNagMhEAfwc32KP@aiRRY1azYULBT6FiEH013DtpIuqwF7yatvrUnajjCXn/PBvJ/D6FRelku2dEUfWUzzeDo2LIuDi4NVGzG53mreNA1fSG9fx7fEyMNOCgBKdwLamD3sM@hKys57T0VhVbkm4M7q51XWrRFo18X1L3ujD1JX7rS4V6/bG7dbqbabynX2Nf01r3Ftbkzd6v9qvkZhTsg8xHNIERYuBHbJsBb9Lu/hP2dkjCd8DF@R9bz8nco1EqMvISANsRRNLsZyoCdQgVsjTpZv)

-1 byte thanks to @amelies: Replace `prod` with `*`. A single operator  can behave as both a monad and dyad in Julia!

Comment: splat (`...`) instead of using `prod` to save 1 byte

Comment: My best attempt with splatting the multiplication is still 37 bytes (`~x=*("#",string.(x,base=16,pad=2)...)`), and `string` has methods that support either splatting or named arguments, but not both.

Comment: I meant `~x="#"*(string.(x,base=16,pad=2)...)`, which seems to use both unadic and dyadic form for `*` at the same time

Answer (score 3):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 25

```bash
printf \#${f=%02x}$f$f $@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnpGZk6pQlJqYYq2Qks9VnFqioKuroBLkGuAT@b@gKDOvJE0hRlmlOs1W1cCoolYlTSVNQcXhf2pyRj5XSn5e6n8DBUMjcwUjU1MuQwUg5DIyMVUwMVYw4jI3AvGNTbgMFICQC6hCAYoB)

Comment: Just me or does this lose against the naive `printf \#%02x%02x%02x $@` at 24 bytes? Also, this is all well-specified in the standard.

Comment: Alternatively, [24 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwZI0Dc3qpaUlaboWOwqKMvNK0hRilK2hLFUDowoFFQeI9E231OSMfK5arjQFAwVDI3MFI1NTINsQBIG0kYmpgomxghGQaW4EEjM2AasEQpCsqSkMQ0xbsABCAwA) in Zsh: `printf \#;printf %02x $@`

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](https://raku.org), <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```raku
{printf '#'~'%02x'x 3,@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/uqAoM68kTUFdWb1OXdXAqEK9QsFYxyG@9n@agoGOoZG5jpGpqTVXmoKhDhCCGEYmpjomxjpGILa5EUjU2ATENtABQrACU1MdKLb@DwA)

*-1 byte thanks to [@IsmaelMiguel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14732/ismael-miguel)*

Comment: You can save 1 byte by using `printf` - https://docs.raku.org/routine/printf - you have to remove the "put" from the test cases, but the output will be in the same line, which doesn't matter.

Comment: Ok, thanks @IsmaelMiguel

Answer (score 3):

## [><> (Fish)](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 102 bytes

Since this challenge is super easy I wanted to try some esolangs.

Takes input as raw byte values.

```
"#"o03i:&82*,01.
 :9)?v68*+o.
v+"W"<;
o14&82*%01.
\.05i:&82*,01.
 06&82*%01.
 07i:&82*,01.
 52&82*%01.
```

[See it in action (animated)](https://mousetail.github.io/Fish/#%7B%22text%22%3A%22%5C%22%23%5C%22o03i%3A%2682*%2C01.%5Cn%20%3A9%29%3Fv68*%2Bo.%5Cnv%2B%5C%22W%5C%22%3C%3B%5Cno14%2682*%2501.%5Cn%5C%5C.05i%3A%2682*%2C01.%5Cn%2006%2682*%2501.%5Cn%2007i%3A%2682*%2C01.%5Cn%2052%2682*%2501.%22%2C%22input%22%3A%22i%245%22%2C%22stack%22%3A%22%22%2C%22mode%22%3A%22numbers%22%7D) - [Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lZKd/AONNKzcJIS8fAUI9LwcpS077MzEJLO1@Pq0xbKVzJxpor39AEpEAVpCBGz8AUWb2BGVxKwcAcWcbUCCbz/39iUjIA)

### Explanation:

This is a function that prints a single hexadecimal number:

```
 :9)?v68*+o.
v+"W"<
o
\.
```

Basically, check if the number is more than 9, if so add "W" ("W"+9 = 'a'), and print it. Otherwise add 6*8='0'. In both cases we use . to "return" from the function.

The function wraps around the left margin since this is "dead space". Since you can't jump to the leftmost

The rest of the code is either of these 2 statements repeated:

```
07i:&82*,01.
```

First 2 values are the return pointer, it's where the function will return. Then we take input and copy 1 value to the register. We divide by 16 (2*8), then push the start address of the print function, and call it with .

The other variant is very similar:

```
14&82*%01.
```

Again 14 is the return value. We take the value form the register, but this time modulo it by 16. Again we call the function at 01.

Notice the last function returns to 52, which is the location of the stray `;` (right of the `<` inside the function) that exits the program.

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 119 bytes

```
"#"oi:&82*,:9)"'"*+"0"+o&82*%:9)"'"*+"0"+oi:&82*,:9)"'"*+"0"+o&82*%:9)"'"*+"0"+oi:&82*,:9)"'"*+"0"+o&82*%:9)"'"*+"0"+o;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/X0lZKT/TSs3CSEvHylJTSV1JS1vJQEk7HySiiiJCTVXW//8nJiUDAA)

Alternate solution that uses just 1 line.

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
"#",`hex@`c$
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwtilEKgCAQBf89xWMTMjCyVQlciI4iRNEB/BCiu2cQw3wMzJmoI5uvo25510qVZBxmXsAxyoyGcIgIHiwLf+2DODSkHfgdVHbpNgSaRq91HSxhXEH23OrTlxdB3hVN)

Takes input as a list of 3 integers.

`` `c$ `` Cast to string (bytes).
`` `hex@ `` Format bytes as hexadecimal values.
`"#",` Prepend a `#`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Bitcoin Cash Script (BitAuth IDE)](https://alpha.ide.bitauth.com/), 601 bytes, 93 bytes as raw bytecode

```bitcoin-cash-script
// Input
<127>
<0>
<255>
// Program
OP_DUP
<16> OP_MOD
OP_SWAP
<16> OP_DIV
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_SWAP
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_CAT
OP_ROT
OP_DUP
<16> OP_MOD
OP_SWAP
<16> OP_DIV
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_SWAP
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_CAT
OP_ROT
OP_DUP
<16> OP_MOD
OP_SWAP
<16> OP_DIV
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_SWAP
OP_DUP <9> OP_GREATERTHAN
OP_IF
<7> OP_ADD
OP_ENDIF
<48> OP_ADD
OP_CAT
OP_ROT
OP_CAT OP_CAT
<'#'> OP_SWAP OP_CAT
// Output string left on stack

// We can also execute it all using raw bytecode
OP_DROP // Clean up
// Input
<127>
<0>
<255>
/// Program
0x7660977c60967659a0635793680130937c7659a0635793680130937e7b7660977c60967659a0635793680130937c7659a0635793680130937e7b7660977c60967659a0635793680130937c7659a0635793680130937e7b7e7e01237c7e
```

[Try it online!](https://ide.bitauth.com/import-template/eJztlFFv0zAQx7-KZZD20jVuSuOlqiaFprA-bIm6jj1QVLnusQYSJ4ovY2jqd-fsMDQkxBMSPPDi8_3u_z_rJNuP_KXVB6gUn_IDYmOnQbArUHV4GOq6CvqiDRwAg4VWWNTmFKFqSoVwei-GvWT4ydaGD_gerG6LxqmoJQGjKqDdDZmxhD0R1wcLsHz6eBzwXu4St1WoD9tG7V363XndU5YrZ-7lhIOALU3T4cbMRqE8pyDcEk4mFKiYt_Vdq6qNyfJtepM7WXTOKLnMUg-vb5NnNF2-e5KyWezR29UiWS9W64vkypeWb0gufSlJ-x6Lq9TTV2c_4b71n-o2T9Y-rrL1_2n-8WkoZ094dvLixIvdkT8oXc2sQ7q4zGJbmDtWwkdktaFU6c8b4xW3wLQyTJW2ZvAAukNgBVJess46U6u-sN1XBF3voZ9mleWMnPMSyNg1vs3vHsizFyIeZBSJWEpNaySjSaxENJ7IeBydidFYxGOpf0lB7v6KEySIUegUwI_uD-mapm6Rfpfpe_56frENRSi2YsI_DPg9tNZ_RuL4DS6ufJw=)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 31 bytes

```C#
(r,g,b)=>$"#{r:X2}{g:X2}{b:X2}"
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86-32 machine code, <strike>28</strike> 27 bytes

```
"\x6a\x23\x58\x99\xaa\xb1\x1c\xac\xd3\xc0\x3c\x0a\x1c\x69\x2f\xaa"
"\xd3\xe8\x30\xce\x75\xf4\x42\x7b\xee\x88\x27"
```

##### Requirements:

- SS:ESP-4 -> 4 bytes of writable memory
- DS:ESI -> 3 bytes of readable memory containing `r`, `g`, `b`
- ES:EDI -> 8 bytes of writable memory to receive NUL-terminated ASCII string (`"#XXXXXX\0"`)
- Direction Flag clear

##### In assembly language:

```
6a 23           push 23h  ; "#"
58              pop eax
99              cdq
aa              stosb
b1 1c           mov cl, 1Ch
__byteloop:
ac              lodsb
d3 c0           rol eax, cl
__nibbleloop:
3c 0a           cmp al, 0Ah  ; someone's old trick for converting a nibble to hex
1c 69           sbb al, 69h
2f              das
aa              stosb
d3 e8           shr eax, cl
30 ce           xor dh, cl
75 f4           jnz __nibbleloop
42              inc edx
7b ee           jnp __byteloop
88 27           mov [edi], ah
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scratch, 235 Bytes

[image: https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/836662188/editor/]

[Link to the editor for the script](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/836662188/editor/)

Source:

```
when gf clicked
set[I v]to(0
set[X v]to[#
repeat(3
change[I v]by(1
set[X v]to(join(x)(join(letter(((item(I)of[C v])-((item(I)of[C v])mod(16)))+(1))of[0123456789ABCDEF])(letter(((item(I)of[C v])mod(16))+(1))of[0123456789ABCDEF
end
say(X
```

It was exhausting to put this into plain text, so I'm not golfing this down YET.

Comment: You can calculate the byte count by using ScratchBlocks syntax https://scratchblocks.github.io

Comment: @noodleman thanks

Comment: You can take input from a Custom Block (the purple ones), you may assume that any variables are initialized at 0 (so you may remove `[set I...]`, and you may output via the X variable as long as it's checked in the interface so you can see it. Idk where the links are but these are all allowed for Scratch posts, you can save bytes with them.

Comment: I would love to accept this, but I'm afraid it's too long.

Comment: @noodleman I think Custom blocks are now pink colored

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 25 bytes

```factor
[ "#%02x%02x%02x"printf ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQll@Um1hSkpmXrpCdWpSXmqNgzWVkYqpgYqxg9D9aQUlZ1cCoAoaVCooy80rSFGL/Jyfm5PwHAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Sequences](https://github.com/nayakrujul/sequences), \$22 \log_{256}(96) \approx 18.1\$ bytes

```
"#"H3x{\016iB2jH}g""JF
```

#### Explanation

```
"#"H3x{\016iB2jH}g""JF
"#"H                    // Push "#" to the list
    3x{         }       // Repeat 3 times:
           i            //   Get a numeric input
         16 B           //   Convert to hexadecimal
       \0    2j         //   Fill with 0s on the left up to 2 characters 
               H        //   Append to the list
                 g      // Get the list
                  ""J   // And join by ""
                     F  // Output the joined string
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 30 bytes

```clj
#(format"#%02x%02x%02x"% %2%3)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU5BCsIwELznFUtLIIEKyTaxBcGPhBysbUSprcYK/j6mqVacnb3sMLNz7MfL03eBtZ0DF3LmRn89TFlOBb6@m1GgSEseOGHt@Ojuxng4QWPBECMKkFgVgFpbANht9pALUTnniJFRi5zvsGpyHmJQ6QJUGY121ZzGRiAxFS7GUv00VQtZb9O/mf@ZCTFT61Tk02bJTCDWEnbz52HqB2AOUn/OeXgD)

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 28 bytes

```
h¦⟨)₵HE¤\⟩¦¦$¦⟨0¤+3⊂ḥ⟩¦$'#¤+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P@PQskfzV2g@atrq4XpoScyj@SsPLTu0TAUsanBoibbxo66mhzuWgsVV1JWBIv@jzY0UDBUMjU1iH7VN/A8A)

28 bytes may seem like a lot of bytes until you discover that there is no "convert a number to hexadecimal as a string" built-in in Gaia. Why was "convert to base 16 as a list of digits" the thing that got added and not to string?

Using a similar algorithm to the 05AB1E and MathGolf answers would probably be longer.

Gaia does not have list input in the input box, so this is a function submission.

### Explained

```
h¦⟨)₵HE¤\⟩¦¦$¦⟨0¤+3⊂ḥ⟩¦$'#¤+
h¦                          # Convert each number to base 16 (list of digits)
  ⟨      ⟩¦¦                 # To each digit in each number:
   )                        #  Increment it to account for 1-indexing
    ₵HE                     #  and index it into the string "0123456789ABCDEF"
       ¤\                   #  Remove some extra junk from the stack
           $¦               # Convert each list to a single string
             ⟨      ⟩¦       # To each hex string:
              0¤+           #  Prepend 0
                 3⊂         #  repeat the first character of the string enough times to make it at least length 3
                   ḥ        #  remove the leading 0
                     $'#¤+  # join into a single string and prepend the # character
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 11 bytes

```
s+\#%L"%02x
```

[Try it online! (test suite)](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=s%2B%5C%23%25L%22%2502x&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B0%2C+127%2C+255%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%5D%0A%5B245%2C+43%2C+2%5D%0A%5B72%2C+1%2C+134%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+0%5D%0A%5B255%2C+255%2C+255%5D&debug=0) Takes a list of integers as input.

**Explanation:**

```
s+\#%L"%02x"Q # Whole program. Closing quote and implicit input (Q) added

     L        #   left map
    %         #   using format operator
      "%02x"  #    this string -> pad leading 0 until length 2, hex form
            Q #   into implicit input 
 +            #  concatenated into
  \#          #   single character '#'
s             # joined into a single string
```

Comment: [Alternative 11 byte solution](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/XztGuTjXzkjbQM/j//9oAx0Fcx0FI1PTWAA) can't find any way to do better though

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 26 bytes

```powershell
'#'+-join($args|% *g 'x2')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZBNb8IwDIbP9FdYolvKVlAb2sEFCQmxHXZgGtIuqJrS4vKhQFmSakzAb@/cdkwl8SV@Xr@2c8i@Uek1SlnY6ehUsDZ77G6zzd6xhVrp8x08rIAdOesUF8s2qM1EaNQwgkWmlqhwGY1PVot5Lvh84AIPQwZAmLU9b5CmKSPoE6QoAVyhX94S8iB0IehTKbvCNOSxx0s44HVpP/iHwdDzh0@s7lnGjW11KtswrKb5G6myrQ6zmov0XtBM9/kOlTCZcjpwhudMTUWy7s7iLSYGaDtbreJy483eLKLI/uy94k9vfpAb4zCXdUiQCJnkUhhcku4e7BTGVGO1Fm/zSa5NtqvNoptPa9W2tR89p8cDaSoLyn0ImSNlJ03rRiNC76hzaRpy6OLXreZiXYriFw)

Ungolfed:

```powershell
'#' + (-join ($args | ForEach-Object -MemberName ToString 'x2' -ArgumentList 'x2'))
```

Straight-forward: takes the rgb arguments, calls the method ToString('x2') for each, joins them, adds the hash.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 54 bytes

```hs
('#':).(((mapM(\_->['0'..'9']++['a'..'f'])"__")!!)=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7BCsIwEETvfsWqhyQ0LWna2CqtF68KghehhhLFqFhFbP19Y9Ig4uweFh4zO2fVXo9NYzSUsDMYjdGMRBjjm3qs8K4O5xViKIrQFMkgqJByt0aSjOp6RIZDUhYFMTd1uVu/8wB@vLpN91zeIQJNoBpAxSjEPKPAhZAUAMIQxoxlWmsLYwvt9gC@MHZjIU8FhTSxVs8d1ILvGbcw496apD@Y5izOJ/6n2//YXi5WiL6NryR9bC/zPuhGnVoTbhfr9Qc) Anonymous function that takes input as a list `[r, g, b]`.

#### Explanation

`mapM(\_->['0'..'9']++['a'..'f'])"__"` constructs the following list:

```hs
["00","01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","0a","0b", ... ,"fd","fe","ff"]
```

`=<<` in this context acts like `concatMap`, so for every element in the input list `[r, g, b]` we index with `!!` into the above list and concatenate the resulting strings. Finally, `('#':)` prepends the leading `#`.

Answer (score 2):

## APL (Dyalog), 41 bytes

```
,/'#'∘,{((⌊⍵÷16)∘⊃,(16⊤⍵)∘⊃)⎕A,⍨⊃,/⍕¨⍳9}¨
```

You can [try it](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%2C%2F%27%23%27%E2%88%98%2C%7B((%E2%8C%8A%E2%8D%B5%C3%B716)%E2%88%98%E2%8A%83%2C(16%E2%8A%A4%E2%8D%B5)%E2%88%98%E2%8A%83)%E2%8E%95A%2C%E2%8D%A8%E2%8A%83%2C%2F%E2%8D%95%C2%A8%E2%8D%B39%7D%C2%A8(255%20255%20200)&run) on **TryAPL**!

- It's 41 bytes assuming a [SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS). In UTF-8 it's about **72 bytes**

The code asumes a list of RGB values as input (Eg. `(255 255 200)`) and returns the hex representation (Eg. `'#FFFFC7'`).

### About this solution

This solution does not rely on having a zero index array environment. The important part is this `⎕A,⍨⊃,/⍕¨⍳9` which generates a string of digits and letters staring at one, like: `123456789ABCDEF.....` which i use to create the hex string. That expression in itself is 11 characters which is a lot. We could do better by using `⎕D,⎕A`; which generates `0123456789ABC......` starting from zero. In an environment that indexes arrays starting from zero that would shave us **6 bytes for free**. But not all APLs are zero indexed. And crucially. Dyalog, which this answer is sadly relying on is NOT zero indexed by default. And to make it zero index we need to use thise expression `⎕IO←0` (Plus `⋄` if we want to just append that to our answer). Which adds those 6 bytes back. So another valid solution would be this one (Also **41 bytes**)

```
⎕IO←0⋄,/'#'∘,{((⌊⍵÷16)∘⊃,(16⊤⍵)∘⊃)⎕D,⎕A}¨
```

The reason this one is important is that. If executed in a Dyalog-compatible environment with `⎕IO←0` by default the answer will reduce to this:

```
,/'#'∘,{((⌊⍵÷16)∘⊃,(16⊤⍵)∘⊃)⎕D,⎕A}¨
```

Which would get us down to **35 bytes**

I'm still very new and I feel this can be improved quite a bit.
Feel free to edit if you have any ideas!

Comment: Nice answer! The outer parentheses can be removed as `¨` returns a function [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R2wQNHX11ZfVHHTN0NKs1NB71dD3q3Xp4u6GZJlDoUVezjoah2aOuJUBBqIDmo76pLjpAwrH20AqgERpGpqYKYGxgoAkA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, isnt the testcase supposed to return `#FFFFC8`?

Comment: You are absolutely right, i forgot to tell TryAPL that this solution asumes ⎕IO←0 So array's can be "zero indexed". Actually, i'm not sure if that can by specified on a sharable url...

Comment: I don't think we can assume variable settings tbh

Comment: I'm pretty sure i've seen some APL solutions here that do! But if it's a big deal i have absolutely no problem with just appending `⎕IO←0⋄` to the solution and adding 6 characters to the total if that's controversial

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-P`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
msG ùT2 i'#
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVA&code=bXNHIPlUMiBpJyM&input=WzEgMSAxXQ)

```
msG ùT2 i'#     :Implicit input of array
m               :Map
 s              :  To string in base
  G             :  16
    ù           :Left pad each
     T          :  With 0s
      2         :  To length 2
        i'#     :Prepend "#"
                :Implicitly join & output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
'#\♠+¢m╞~
```

Port of [my 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254084/52210), so also input as list [r,g,b] and outputs in uppercase.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/19dOebRzAXahxblPpo6r@7//2hDHSCM5Yo2MjHVMTHWMQIyzcFixiZApoGOoZG5jpGpKZgNhCCVpqY6UBwLAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
'#        '# Push character "#"
  \        # Swap so the (implicit) input-triplet is at the top
   ♠+      # Add 256 to each value in the triplet
     ¢     # Convert each to an hexadecimal string
      m╞   # Remove the leading "1" from each string
        ~  # Pop and dump the contents of the triplet to the stack
           # (after which the entire stack is joined together and output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
#Ｆ³﹪%02xＮ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRENJWUnTmistv0hBw1hTASLmm59SmpOvoaRqYFShpKPgmVdQWuJXmpuUWqShqalp/f@/KZehuSGXscF/3bIcAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs in lower case. Explanation:

```
#
```

Output the leading `#`.

```
Ｆ³
```

Repeat thrice.

```
﹪%02xＮ
```

Input the next integer and format it as two hexadecimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 49 bytes

```
func[r g b][to-hex/size to 1 to#{}reduce[r g b]6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BCsIwEETv@YoBz6JJsxb8DK8hB5tsrBcjsQVR/PaoSdOFWXaYfUxin0/sYawIxxzmmzMJFwzWTHE78nP3uL4YU4T8rc37k9jPjpefg80hJj67EY0SKLOHVD0U0eJlU/FKE6C7/1XzXpVcdnrlV1WCqElYc09xYATUzvwF)

## 53 bytes

```
func[r g b][probe to-hex/size(r << 16)+(g << 8)+ b 6]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1BCsIwFET3OcUsW4po0qQV6SnchixM@9O6MSUqiJePNDH98GCG4fEDTfFKE7Rh7hLd@zHqgBnW6DV4S3j5w0Kf4/P@pSpgGMC7uqnmLZ3rBhadic4Huo0LismQ7gQuegil/p0XUhdSAbLdUt57kXbeyt3fyYZSBWa0Q/4Wfw)

It's shorter to `probe` the hex value instead of return it, because it `mold`s the value and keeps its literal representation.

Alternative:

## 62 bytes

```
func[r g b][h: func[c][to-hex/size c 2]rejoin["#"h r h g h b]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY3BDsIgEETv/YpJPRuFQpr0M7wSDkpB8ABmWxPjz2MF6SYv2cnszJKd88XOULpzU3avaBThjptWfkKRRqs1Hb19n5bwsTDgmuwjhaj6Q@9B8Nu93xI6u0T2ajxaRYcyZzA@gkv516xRNBcSEMNvq/7Ii88Gsed3akLKRqfVk0Jc4VB/5i8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 14 bytes

```
O'#;S*g+E8TB16
```

Takes numbers as command-line arguments; outputs to stdout. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJPJyM7UypnK0U4VEIxNiIsIiIsIiIsIjUgMTcxIDMwIl0=)

#### Explanation

Same basic approach as [Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254084/16766):

```
O'#;S*g+E8TB16
O'#;            Output a # symbol without a trailing newline
      g         List of command-line args
       +        To each, add
        E8      2 to the 8th power (256)
          TB16  Convert each to its base-16 string representation
    S*          All but first character of each
                Concatenate and autoprint (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATLAB](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 38 bytes

```matlab
@(r,g,b) ['#' num2str([r g b],'%02X')]
```

Using builtin num2str formatting to convert to a 2-field width hexadecimal value, and prepending a '#' character.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNIJ10nSVMhWl1ZXSGvNNeouKRII9pQwUjBOFZHXdXAKEJdM/b/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 60 bytes

```go
import."fmt"
func f(r,g,b int){Printf("#%06x",r<<16|g<<8|b)}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9BCoMwEEX3nmJQCgqxJqlRF6Fn6BVUOiKtWsRCQXuSbqTQXS_Ue_QAjVFB-zMwm5f_5z-eWdW_L3F6irMjFHFevq4NutFH5sWlqputiUVjGngtU0C7JhlJIC8bpz3UaqFtWhsa3ExSS8mCLpMy6hLnPnl89bfB1HZaA21KgPGQABcCABzPc_dgURoioqH9zgpUHFOcGhg1c2x4K477goC_U4YLDgVPKF9xIR8Nd_6C8yPKomDFqfuG-cvVWucKoUuMTeZcLWPq3vfj_gE)

Port of [@mousetail's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254081/rgb-to-hexadecimal/254095#254095).

Answer (score 1):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 69 bytes

```
import strutils
proc f(r,g,b:int)=echo'#'&toHex(r shl 16+g shl 8+b,6)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZBNCoMwEIX3nmJAqBEjJDFRKbS7Qs-hGBX8I0boXboRSpc9UG_TJFZK38xi4GPePOb-GNp-XZ-LlnH-vrT9NCoNs1aLbrvZm9RYgkQK17g4toMOT1XZjIEfHPR4rW5Iwdx0QNOodkMeFTgNv2YviQgGyjIMTIjQB4D4DD4hmZTSk4gaaNoB2CG1ZSDjAgNPzOrGLZSCFYQZmLFtNeE_yHNC89RzN23_2zpZWyFcmj2Ss3XaQu-f-AA)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP 8.x, <s>44</s> 41 bytes

This simply creates an anonymous function that displays the expected value.

```php
fn(...$a)=>'#'.bin2hex(pack('C*',...$a));
```

### How does it work?

This anonymous function receives the arguments in the RGB order.

Then, it packs the arguments into binary unsigned chars, using [`pack('C*', ...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php).
In essence, this binary string contains ASCII characters, from the values to be packed.

The resulting binary string is converted to hexadecimal using [`bin2hex()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php).
Each byte (`0`-`255`) is already 0-padded on the left, by the function, saving a lot of work.

### Example of usage

A simple example:

```php
$fn = fn(...$a)=>'#'.bin2hex(pack('C*',...$a));

// Should display: #ff4002
echo $fn(255, 64, 2);
```

You can try this on: https://onlinephp.io/c/4470e

---

---

### Old version, 44 bytes

```php
fn(...$a)=>printf("#%'02x%'02x%'02x",...$a);
```

### How does it work?

The function `printf` displays the arguments formatted by a format specifier.
However, by default, it displays the value padded by spaces, instead of `0`.
As such, it is required to specify the character with `'0`.

You also need to specify that it is a 2-char long hex value, which you do with `%2x`.

Using the spread operator, I can put all arguments into an array and spread them on the function call, saving precious bytes.

---

You can try this online on: https://onlinephp.io/c/effd1

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 38 bytes

```rust
|r,g,b|format!("#{:06x}",r<<16|g<<8|b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcPRCoMgFADQd7/iZi8Kd2COapTbT@wDhoE3gmVMDQbZt7uXHThhj6mQh9UuXkg42NsloAHIi/2q8V9eHs8UFj/DveSAM06ZtrDaVAleH4PqvifHYEzT5dmYW55kGZmN0YX0cp9KkFAIje4RdNtKBF4r1RMRlyM7yw8)

A `fn(u32,u32,u32) -> String`.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 48 bytes

```
"#",,/{$[1=#t:"0123456789abcdef"@16\x;"0",t;t]}'
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs1JSVtLR0a9WiTa0VS6xUjIwNDI2MTUzt7BMTEpOSU1TcjA0i6mwVjJQ0imxLomtVefiSovWMFQAQs1YENPI1FQBiqECJqYKJsYKRhCeuRFIqbGJZiwAYvYYow==)

I really wish ngn/k has built-in hexadecimal converter. Takes a list of number `[r, g, b]`.

Explanation:

```
"#",,/{$[1=#t:"0123456789abcdef"@16\x;"0",t;t]}' Main function. Takes implicit input
                                               ' For each number in the list...
      {                                       }  Execute a function that
       $[                                    ]   Checks if
                                 16\x            The number turned into base 16 (a list)
              "0123456789abcdef"                 The string "0123456789abcdef"
                                @                at each number in the sub-list
            t:                                   Assigned to variable `t`
           #                                     Length
         1=                                      Is equal to 1
                                     ;           If so, then
                                      "0",t      Add a `0` before `t`
                                           ;t    Else, just return `t`
    ,/                                           Join every hexadecimal strings of each
                                                 number together
   ,                                             Concat with
"#"                                              The string "#"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 47 bytes

```
3:1(?v$:82*%}82*,:1%-}1-!
+ob1.>~"#"or:9)7*+"0"
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/39jKUMO@TMXKwkhLtRZI6FgZqurWGuoqcmnnJxnq2dUpKSvlF1lZappraSsZKP3//1@3zACIDY3MgaSRqSkA)

**Explanation**

```
3:1(?v                  !  # Loop the rest of the 1st row 3 times then move down
      $:82*%}82*,:1%-}1-   # Convert each input to pair of hex numbers
     >~"#"or               # Discard counter, print "#" and reorder stack
            :9)7*+         # add 7 if it's supposed to be a letter (>9)
+o                "0"      # add 48 to get from 1 to "1" for example
  b1.                      # handle the next number (jump to line 4 in explanation)
```

Answer (score 1):

## POSIX shell, 24 bytes

```
printf \#;printf %02x $@
```

[Try it online!](https://glot.io/snippets/gh04zq28vz)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
'#',16,@}.@hfd@,]
```

Accepts a list of ints. Prepending 16 is for unconditional padding. Thanks to Jonah for the -1.

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70wa8FOJT31NAVbKwV1BR0FAwUrINbVU3AO8nFbWlqSpmuxUV1ZXcfQTMehVs8hIy3FQScWIn7TTpMrNTkjXyFNzQ6ox9DIXMHI1NTaUAEIrY1MTBVMjBWMrM2NQHxjE2sDoBoDa6AKBSiGmLJgAYQGAA)

Comment: I think you can change the 255 to 99 for the same effect.

Comment: Ah yes, anything in `16..255` would work. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü↨▌/¶$ø∟
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8117dd2f1424001c&i=%5B0,+127,+255%5D%0A%5B1,+1,+1%5D%0A%5B245,+43,+2%5D%0A%5B72,+1,+134%5D%0A%5B0,+0,+0%5D%0A%5B255,+255,+255%5D&m=2)

Unpacks to the following:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 bytes

```
{2:hm'#s+
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7B2%3Ahm%27%23s%2B&i=%5B0,+127,+255%5D%0A%5B1,+1,+1%5D%0A%5B245,+43,+2%5D%0A%5B72,+1,+134%5D%0A%5B0,+0,+0%5D%0A%5B255,+255,+255%5D&m=2)

```
{2:hm'#s+
{   m     # map the following over each value in the input array
  :h      # convert to hex, padded with zeroes to length
 2        # 2
     '#   # string literal "#"
       s  # swapped before the hex string
        + # and added
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 55 Bytes

```python
lambda x:'#'+''.join(hex(y)[2:].rjust(2,'0')for y in x)
```

Input is given as an iterable. Iterates through the list, converts to hex, snipps of the `0x`, makes sure each hex number is of length 2, joins it together and prepends a `#`.

[Run on TIO](https://tio.run/##HcJLCoAgEADQqwgtZqSQPrQJOkm1MEoyahSz0NNb9Hg2@s1Qk1Q/pkOe8yJZ6CCDHEDsRhNua8DIh7qbhNvvy2NdQAlcGcci08QCT9Zp8qhwfeSBmuztkX9S1Rb/Fw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), <del>65</del> 45 bytes

Saved 20 bytes thanks to @The Thonnu

---

Golfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDdSsMwFMfxNk9xqAjJloWtXTsZTPFS0KuhCGNIOrOa0aYlTffB2JN4oxd64xPNpzFrOj_gnCTn5P__5ZCXj3LGUx58TryOyldcK2_6dfIgsyLXBhZ8yVllZMrGM66U0Ajl8ULMDNxyqWCLAJ7EHDJbYK6TcghXWvPNZGy0VMmUDOFOSQOjWgmw5CmUDmR7SqygweLxpjQiY1KRWrh6lqnARleCNFZnlqqoDrgGwpRYmxupBCZ_RDqJ73laidIKawMri1Qa7FHwCMt4gR-Zya-VOZoKO6xJFZ7nOuMG__hxl9BfGu79q3xCnH-HDonc2w4xBGzxtEkyunD_Yed5r8y8c77vYE0TGtubrXfqtb2zbrT22PH9VhSGQdROWn4YtWOyc6a3Zn_dX3Yp9PwBBT8MUc-ebSC_H1LoB7aJBr7rBX1klYdAVlnL68VxvgE)

```scala
(r,g,b)=>{"#"+"%06x".format(r*65536+g*256+b)}
```

Ungolfed version. [Attempt this online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVFdS8MwFMXX_IpLRUiwhrXbmBREfBT0aeiLiKQzqxlpWtLbfSD7Jb7sRR_8R_przJJuKoOb3ORwzkk49-2jmQgt-pvNe4vTs_Pvo09V1pVFmIm54C0qzccTYYy0hFT5TE4QboUy8EoAnuUUSnehwhZNBlfWitXDGK0yxSPL4M4ohAvPBJgLDU0wcpiRC-hs6XjVoCy5MswTFy9KS4q2layTBrEydbu160y4kUu8UUZS9odki_xe6FY2jugFvKm1QhrFEDFeipo-cayuDe5EtfssakOnlS0F0r2e9lj860aTf7eUsaBfk-3qkthZZOD8Yyi6nvvu4gjB7AOJjiM4heikly4jvtOyA6g4hHLmn12TMLJucpuvy14MSTqKIR0OSeLOrkg6GMYw6DuQjNKA9QfEMbdFHNPT_RZ8fgA)

```scala
import java.util.Scanner

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
    while(true) {
      val input = scanner.nextLine()
      val rgbValues = input.split(", ").map(_.toInt)
      println(format(rgbValues(0), rgbValues(1), rgbValues(2)))
    }
  }

  def format(r: Int, g: Int, b: Int): String = {
    "#" + "%02x".format(r) + "%02x".format(g) + "%02x".format(b)
  }
}
```

Comment: [45 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VZDdSsMwFMfxNk9xqAjJloWtXTsZTPFS0KuhCGNIOrOa0aYlTffB2JN4oxd64xPNpzFrOj_gnCTn5P__5ZCXj3LGUx58TryOyldcK2_6dfIgsyLXBhZ8yVllZMrGM66U0Ajl8ULMDNxyqWCLAJ7EHDJbYK6TcghXWvPNZGy0VMmUDOFOSQOjWgmw5CmUDmR7SqygweLxpjQiY1KRWrh6lqnARleCNFZnlqqoDrgGwpRYmxupBCZ_RDqJ73laidIKawMri1Qa7FHwCMt4gR-Zya-VOZoKO6xJFZ7nOuMG__hxl9BfGu79q3xCnH-HDonc2w4xBGzxtEkyunD_Yed5r8y8c77vYE0TGtubrXfqtb2zbrT22PH9VhSGQdROWn4YtWOyc6a3Zn_dX3Yp9PwBBT8MUc-ebSC_H1LoB7aJBr7rBX1klYdAVlnL68VxvgE)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 39 bytes

```
ResourceFunction["ColorToHex"]@(#/255)&
```

## Mathematica (without `ResourceFunction`), 42 bytes

```
"#"<>IntegerString[#~FromDigits~256,16,6]&
```

[View them on Wolfram Cloud!](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/cb9ce861-c8db-462b-9584-c3ddcb14b61d)

Answer (score 0):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 32 bytes

```apl
{'#',∊{{(⍵+1)⌷⎕D,⎕A}¨⍵⊤⍨2⍴16}¨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RqdWV1nUcdXdXVGo96t2obaj7q2f6ob6qLDpBwrD20Aij4qGvJo94VRo96txiaQURqgXo1jExNFcDYwEATAA)

I'm quite sure this could be tacit, I'm just bad at it.

```apl
{'#',∊{{(⍵+1)⌷⎕D,⎕A}¨⍵⊤⍨2⍴16}¨⍵}
{     {                        }¨⍵} ⍝ For every number in the input
                       ⍵⊤⍨         ⍝ Convert to
                            2⍴       ⍝ 2 digits of
                              16     ⍝ Base 16
       {             }¨              ⍝ For every digit
              ⌷                      ⍝ Index
        (⍵+1)                       ⍝ Digit + 1
               ⎕D,⎕A                ⍝ Into '0123456789ABCDEFGHI...'
      ∊                              ⍝ Flatten
  '#',                               ⍝ Prepend a '#'
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io/), 17 bytes

```
$[b]->to :color b
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?bdERwV)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 47 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K05OzEn8n5@UlZpcouCbmJmnUP0/JTVNIVejyMozr0QnHUwmgUhN2zQlZZUiVQOjCpV0MJkEIpX@cykogLUAdWskFqUXWyk4FhUlVkYHlxRl5qXHalophOZllijYKlQDVSooFABFS3LyNHI1jExNdRRghKYmmqyBjgIIYYgbGlnoKBhaGukoWJiDJWu5av8DAA)!

```scala
def m(r:Int,g:Int,b:Int)=f"#$r%02x$g%02x$b%02x"
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 36 bytes

```lua
print(('#%02x%02x%02x'):format(...))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ11Z1cCoAobVNa3S8otyE0s09PT0NDX///9vZGL638T4vxEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [ARBLE](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/ARBLE), 29 bytes

```lua
format("#%02x%02x%02x",b,g,r)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyxKykn9/z8tvyg3sURDSVnVwKgChpV0knTSdYo0////b2hk/t/gv5GpKQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```
import colors
proc h(r,g,b:int)=echo rgb(r,g,b)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m704LzN3wYKlpSVpuhY39TNzC_KLShSS83Pyi4q5CorykxUyNIp00nWSrDLzSjRtU5Mz8hWK0pMgYpoQbTsyNIxMTHUUTIx1FIw0uTI0DHQUQAgqDTMdAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 30 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⊂@#♭∵($"__"∩(⍥(+@W)>9.)⌊⊃÷◿16)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__ZiDihpAg4oqCQCPima3iiLUoJCJfXyLiiKko4o2lKCtAVyk-OS4p4oyK4oqDw7fil78xNikKCmYgWzAgMTI3IDI1NV0KZiBbMSAxIDFdCmYgWzI0NSA0MyAyXQpmIFs3MiAxIDEzNF0KZiBbMCAwIDBdCmYgWzI1NSAyNTUgMjU1XQo=)